# Typekit: the domain isn't in the list of published domains for kit

Tags: angular, typekit

I have used this script to load typekit. But it is giving error on console "Typekit: the domain localhost.nextIn.net isn't in the list of published domains for kit"

```
<script async src="//use.typekit.net/mto5gmx.js"></script>
<script>
try {
    Typekit.load({
        async: true
    });
} catch (e) {}
</script>
```